# AudioKit MIDI - Creating Virtual Outputs in Swift

Tags: midi, audiokit

I want to create an Virtual Output port in my app, which can be recognised by other music apps.

Example is iSymphonic, were one is able to select a VO from a list generated by MIDIFlow.

I have tried `.createVirtualPorts()` which does **not** throw errors, but at the same time does not create VO's that are visible in iSymphonic.

Comment: Hello, please take a time to go through the welcome tour to know your way around here , read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Please include code of what you have tried yourself in your question.